# Heroku "MFA Verification using a Recovery Code" does work

Tags: heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/recovery-codes#mfa-verification-using-a-recovery-code

If you want to log in but don’t have your primary MFA verification method available, you can easily log in with a pre-generated recovery code.

Select Choose Another Option.
Enter a recovery code.
Each recovery code is good for one use only. Codes remain valid until they’re used.

---

Choose another option... isnt an option. Locked out of Heroku account after changing phones and their documentation is inaccurate. Any help?

Comment: Incredibly... This page about the topic redirects to a login page.
https://help.heroku.com/7IDU8QZZ/what-should-i-do-if-i-m-locked-out-of-my-heroku-account

Comment: I'm having the same issue @heroku.  If you select the forgotten password option, the next screen has an email to contact:  account-lockout@heroku.com